# can't boot after updating to 19.04 from 18.10

Tags: boot, 19.04

After updating from 18.10 to 19.04, I get this message on boot...

```
PKCS#7 Signature not signed with a trusted key.
```

I can't get any further.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Try turning off `secure boot` in your BIOS. If that doesn't allow you to boot, we'll have to troubleshoot a possible (video) driver problem. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I've couldn't boot from Legacy. I also managed to boot into recovery mode. Purged the old Nvidea drivers and installed the new recommended Nvidea drivers. I still have the same problem.

Comment: It's not a "legacy" thing, it's a `secure boot` thing with an unsigned driver. What version Nvidia driver did you install? To quickly eliminate the Nvidia driver as the source of your problem, go ahead and purge it, reboot, and see if it works. Otherwise, to get more specific information, do `grep -i -B 4 -A 4 PKCS /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: It's strange because it's a fairly new build (about a year ago), but the bios has nothing about secure boot listed that I could find. I'll try those other things tomorrow as it's pretty late here and I need to sleep. Thanks.
Edit: I think the new Nvidia driver was 410. I got the instructions here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: FYI... if it supports your card, 418 is the latest Nvidia driver.

Comment: Just checked, and I did install the 418 drivers. Here's the output of the grep command https://pastebin.com/Si3FVsCZ - Thanks

Comment: Boot to recovery mode (if you can't boot normally) and show me `dkms status`. Use imgur.com to post a screenshot if need be.

Comment: nik@nik:~$ dkms status
virtualbox, 6.0.6, 4.18.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.0.6, 5.0.0-13-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: I also purged the Nvidia drivers and didn't replace them. The system booted without problems.

Comment: Contact Nvidia support for help. This is the second time this morning I've come across this with 418.56 and 19.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @heynnema said, purging the Nvidia drivers and rebooting, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes nvidia is not helping ubuntu user base:

```sh
sudo journalctl  -f

Aug 02 18:52:44 wsf1127 k3s[2235]: time="2019-08-02T18:52:44.521923189+02:00" level=error msg="failed to get CA certs at https://[FFFF:FFFF:2f37:FFFF:3ed9:2bff:FFFF:FFFF]:6443/cacerts: Get https://[FFFF:FFFF:2f37:FFFF:3ed9:2bff:FFFF:FFFF]:6443/cacerts: dial tcp [FFFF:FFFF:2f37:FFFF:3ed9:2bff:FFFF:FFFF]::6443: connect: connection refused"


sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'

sudo reboot
```